# Using $.when().done() to wait for downloading complete

Tags: jquery

I wanna download multiple json files and compress data to a cookie. First of all, I save them to an array, then I use `JSON.stringify()` to compress it.

I've tried:

```
var files = [];
$.when(
    ['file1', 'file2', 'file3'].forEach(function (f) {
        $.getJSON('/scripts/json/' + f + '.json', function (data) {
            files.push(data);
            console.log(files) // checking ok
        })
    })
).done(
    console.log(files); // Oops... this line will be excuted before $.when()
    $.cookie('files', JSON.stringify(files)) // compress before saving
)
```

As you can see, jquery compiler won't know exactly when the files are downloaded complete.

So, my question is: How to `wait` them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating inside `$.when`, but you're not passing the Deferreds back, so `$.when` only receives the returned result from `Array.forEach`, which is always `undefined`, so basically what you're doing is

```
$.when(undefined).done();
```

You can to **pass** an array to `$.when` if you use `apply`, and mapping, using `map()` instead of `forEach()` would return an array of the Deferreds

```
$.when.apply($,
    ['file1', 'file2', 'file3'].map(function (f) {
        return $.getJSON('/scripts/json/' + f + '.json');
    })
).then(function() {
    var files = [].slice.call(arguments).map(function(x) { return x[0]; });
    $.cookie('files', JSON.stringify(files)) // compress before saving
}, function(err) {
     // failed
});
```

Comment: I think in `then` you'll need to use `arguments` as it gets results from each deferred as a separate argument, so: `.then(function() { var files = arguments; ...`

Comment: interesting, [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) says different thing. Will take it into account next time. Thanks

Comment: @faron - You're right, `then()` would return three arguments, one for each ajax call, and each one being an array of `[data, textStatus, jqXHR]`, so mapping the arguments and returning the first item in each array, being the `data`, would create a files array suitable for storing in a cookie like the OP wants

Comment: @faron - it "converts" the arguments object into an array, so `Array.map` can be used on it.